# How can I have a venv in Atom by default?

Tags: python, python-venv

I recently switched to Atom and I noticed that it doesn't have a venv by default when starting a new project. Is there any way I can have it do that everytime I start a project like PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install this package in atom, https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-virtualenv

Comment: Is the venv already activated when I install it?